# How can I order data for display on iOS using Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I am trying to order my data by TimeStamp but, it does not seem to be working. My Feed class is down below. Can someone please take a look and tell me what is going on. I believe the problem is in the checkForUpdates() function. I have tried everything to get the data to order by timestamp. When I remove the loadData() function the apps displayed the posts in order by timestamp, but new post always go to the end of the view.[image: Feed not ordered by timnestamp]

import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class FeedVC: UITableViewController {

```
var db = Firestore.firestore()
var postArray = [Posts]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //db = Firestore.firestore()
```

//loadData()
      // checkForUpdates()

```
}
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
     checkForUpdates()
    loadData()



}

func loadData() {
    db.collection("posts").getDocuments() {
        querySnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            self.postArray = querySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({Posts(dictionary: $0.data())})
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


}

func checkForUpdates() {
    db.collection("posts").order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true)
    .addSnapshotListener {
            querySnapshot, error in

            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}

            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach {
                diff in

                if diff.type == .added {
                    self.postArray.append(Posts(dictionary: diff.document.data())!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

    }
}

@IBAction func composePost(_ sender: Any) {





    let composeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "New Post", message: "Enter your name and message", preferredStyle: .alert)

    composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Your name"
    }

    composeAlert.addTextField { (textField:UITextField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Your message"
    }

    composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    composeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in do {


        if let name = composeAlert.textFields?.first?.text, let content = composeAlert.textFields?.last?.text {

            let newSweet = Posts(name: name, content: content, timeStamp: Timestamp())

            var ref:DocumentReference? = nil
            ref = self.db.collection("posts").addDocument(data: newSweet.dictionary) {
                error in

                if let error = error {
                    print("Error adding document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }else{
                    print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
                }

            }

        }
        }

    }))

    self.present(composeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}



// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return postArray.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let post = postArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(post.name): \(post.content)"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(post.timeStamp.dateValue())"

    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use order by: while loading the data

```
chats.order(by: "createdTime", descending: false)
```

Comment: You have pointed me in the right direction. Thank you. But for some reason the new posts always go to the bottom and not the top of the tableview.

Comment: make descending: true

Answer (score 0):

you can simply assign false  `descending: false`

```
    func checkForUpdates() {
    db.collection("posts").order(by: "timeStamp", descending: false)
    .addSnapshotListener {
      querySnapshot, error in

          guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}

               snapshot.documentChanges.forEach {
                 diff in

                 if diff.type == .added {
                   self.postArray.append(Posts(dictionary: diff.document.data())!)
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.tableView.reloadData()
                     }
                  }
               }

           }
        }
```

OR
You can simply reverse your array as below

```
func checkForUpdates() {
    db.collection("posts").order(by: "timeStamp", descending: true)
    .addSnapshotListener {
        querySnapshot, error in

          guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}

             snapshot.documentChanges.forEach {
              diff in

               if diff.type == .added {
                  self.postArray.append(Posts(dictionary: diff.document.data())!)
               }
               self.postArray.reversed()
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

          }
       }
```